# vue+element-ui program Error when running 'npm run dev'

Tags: npm, vue.js, loader

get this error

[image]

my workmate can run in his computer.

Did I miss some loaders?

Comment: Try running npm not from project folder, but from vue folder inside it

Comment: how to run npm from vue folder?

Comment: It depends what platform you're working on, it might work or the problem could lie somewhere else, it won't hurt to try. Open your project and look for 'vue-project' folder. Change the cmd location to that directory and then run npm